# I have to sack a temporary worker. How to communicate it?

Tags: conflict-aversion, work-environment

I contracted a temporary worker for two weeks, to cover vacations of another person. There is no contract, only a word agreement. His work is to cover a turn during the night, checking some systems during his turn.
The problem is that in his first week, this worker did some things that deserve a sack. He left the working place for several hours, he allowed two of his friends (two girls, I don't have details) to enter to the office and, finally, he had an argument with these friends, that demanded the intervention of the guards of the building.

The point is, since I have to sack him, how can I communicate him that I have to sack him? While explaining him that he made several mistakes, in order to make him peacefully accept his fate?

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that the sacking will not be peaceful? You described your reasons quite well, however you have not described the interpersonal issue at all. Are you just inexperienced perhaps? Do you know him personally? Please explain further

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure you really need to explain much here. They were a temporary worker who displayed flagrant disrespect for the work they were tasked to do. Unless locale demands it I would let them know like this:

> This arrangement isn't going to work. Thank you for your time.

That's it. This would be the time to ask for keys or anything like that. If they ask why simply say:

> It just isn't working.

or

> This just isn't a good fit.

I say this based on my experience having to fire a number of people over a number of years. I work in the US, which practices at will employment, meaning you can be terminated at any time for any reason. As stated before your locale may have different standards. If so, read on.

---

However, if you feel absolutely compelled for legal or ethical considerations be brief and to the point.

> You are being relieved because your actions the other night compromised our security.

Or unacceptable conduct or some other reasonable justification based on what you mentioned. Don't engage in any further discussion or arguments. If they argue simply restate your position.

> I understand what you are saying but we cannot employ you further.

repeat as needed. This will eventually get the message across that the decision was final before he was brought in to the discussion.

---

If you are concerned with his possible peacefulness, have security present.